# Determine the values of c and d so that E[Y] = c and Var(Y ) = 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, density-function

**Question**

Supppose $X$ is a random PDF $f(x)=\frac{2x}{c^{2}d^{2}}, \quad 0<x<cd$ where $c > 0, \; d > 0$.

Determine the values of $c$ and $d$ so that $\mathbb{E}[X]= c $ and $\mathrm{Var}(x) = 1$

**My approach**

My approach has been to try and isolate the variables using the given information. I have used $\mathrm{Var}(X) = 1$ as a reference point to start. My work has been as follows:

\begin{align}
    1 &= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 \\
    1 &= \int_{0}^{cd} x^{2} \cdot \frac{2x}{c^{2}d^{2}} - \left(\int_{0}^{cd} x \cdot \frac{2x}{c^{2}d^{2}}\right)^2
\end{align}

Following this, I have approached this result:
\begin{align}
 1 = \frac{(cd)^4}{2c^2d^2} - \frac{(cd)^4}{c^4d^4}
\end{align}

Which yields the following:
\begin{align}
    1 &= \frac{c^2d^2}{2} \\
    2 &= c^2d^2 \\
\end{align}

I have then derived the possible inter solutions of $c$ and $d$.

\begin{align*}
        \therefore c &= \pm 1\; ,\pm 2 \\
    d &= \pm 1\; , \pm 2
\end{align*}

I have then tried to prove the $\mathbb{E}[X] = c$ through the following case. Suppose $c = 1$ and $d = 2$ thus $0 < x < 2$.

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[X] &= \int_{0}^{2} x\cdot \frac{2y}{c^{2}d^{2}} \; \mathrm{d}y \\
    &= \int_{0}^{2} \frac{2x^2}{4} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
    &= \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2} 2x^2 \; \mathrm{d}x \\
    &= \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2x^3}{3} \Biggr|_{0}^{2}
\end{align}

However, the answer does not evalute to the case. I have taken the wrong approach and am lost on how to approach the problem. Any help with the solution would be really appreciated.

**Update**

Thank you for the suggestions. Errors were made in the integration. The error was found within the 2nd integral.

$$
\frac{(cd)^4}{c^4d^4} \rightarrow \frac{2(cd)^3}{3(c^4d^4)}
$$

Squaring the results would give the following $\frac{4c^2d^2}{9}$

The derivation of the expected value for $c$ is as follows

\begin{align}
    c &= \int_{0}^{ac} x \cdot \frac{2x}{c^2d^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
    c &= \frac{2}{c^2d^2} \int_{0}^{cd} x^2 \\
    c &= \frac{2}{c^2d^2} \cdot \frac{x^3}{3} \Biggr|_{0}^{cd} \\
    c &= \frac{2x^3}{3c^2d^2} \xrightarrow[]{} \frac{2(cd)^3}{3c^2d^2} \\
    c &= \frac{2}{3}cd \\
    &\therefore d = \frac{3}{2}
\end{align}

Following that, the answer would be simply substituting it into the corrected equation for variance.

\begin{align}
    1 &= \frac{1}{2}c^2\cdot \frac{9}{4} - \frac{4}{9}c^2\cdot\frac{9}{4} \\
    1 &= \frac{9}{4}c^2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{9}\right) \\
    18 &= \frac{9}{4}c^2 \\
    8 &= c^2 \\
    c &= 2\sqrt{2}
\end{align}.

Comment: It seems like there is an error in your calculation for expectation (the second integral in your variance). There seems to be a $4/9$ missing.

Comment: Note that $c,d$ need not be integers.  Whatever $\mathbb{E}[X]$ evaluates to is $c$, so there's no way for your answer to "not evaluate to the case" (you have at least a couple errors though... in addition to the above comment's point, if you did have $c^2d^2=2$, then you'd have $cd = \sqrt{2}$, so your candidate values of $c$ and $d$ wouldn't work)

Comment: Thank you! I think that makes more sense upon reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick way to solve this. Brief hints are provided for the path to follow. Reveal the spoilers if you get stuck in computations.

You have $\mathbb E[X]=c$. Then put this into the Variance equation.

> \begin{align*}1=\mathrm Var[X]&=\mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2\\&=\int_{0}^{cd}x^2\frac{2x}{c^2d^2}\ \mathrm dx-c^2\\&=\frac12c^2d^2-c^2\end{align*}

For the expectation, you have

> $$c=\int_{0}^{cd}x\frac{2x}{c^2d^2}\ \mathrm dx=\frac{2}{3}cd\Rightarrow d=\frac32$$

Plugging this in, we get

> $$1=\frac12c^2\frac94-c^2=\frac{c^2}{8}\Rightarrow c=2\sqrt 2$$

and you are done.

Comment: I think the preference around here would be to have the OP do at least some work getting to the answer instead of solving everything for him right off the bat...

Comment: Fair, I will just put things inside spoiler bars so that if they get stuck, they can take hints. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No thank you, I think you've pointed out really big error in my calculations. Thank you! There is indeed a 4/9 I've missed. I have stared too long at it and its become all a blur to me. Thank you again.

Comment: @HackR +1, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry, I am having a hard time following what you were trying to do. You are given that the pdf of $X$ is $f(x)=\frac{2x}{c^{2}d^{2}}$ with $c,d>0$ and $0<x<cd$.

The first sanity check is that your pdf has to be non-negative everywhere and integrate to $1$. You have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx
 = \int_0^{cd} \frac{2x}{c^{2}d^{2}}\ dx
 = \left. \frac{x^2}{c^2 d^2} \right|_0^{cd}
 = 1,
$$
so this makes sense. To find the expected value, compute
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]
 = \int_0^{cd} xf(x)\ dx = \int_0^{cd} x \frac{2x}{c^2d^2} dx
 = \frac{2}{c^2d^2} \int_0^{cd} x^2dx = \frac{2cd}{3}.
$$
However, you are given that $\mathbb{E}[X]= c$, so we must have $d = 3/2$.

Now to find the variance, as you did, note that
$$
\mathbb{Var} X
 = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2
 = \int_0^{cd} x^2 f(x)\ dx - c^2
 = \int_0^{cd} x^2 \frac{2x}{c^2d^2} dx - c^2.
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your input! It seems I have made an error in my integration.